# Where would be the location of my project when running in R studio connect server

Tags: r, rstudio-server, shinyapps

I have a concern here. Below is simple application. When I run this code, I get location of my project in my R console (since I have print(getwd()) at the last line). But when I deploy this in my Rstudio connect server or shinyapps.io. When can I see this location. In fact it will no more be my local system. So I have 2 questions here

What would be my location (getwd()) when I deploy this application to RStudio connect server or Shinyapps,io
Where can I see this print?
Can you please make me understand.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  textInput("name", "Name: "),
  textOutput("greeting"),
  selectInput("Slider","Slider",choices = unique(iris$Species))
  )
  )
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$greeting <- renderText({
    paste0("Hello, ", input$name, "!")
  })
  print(getwd())
  })
```